# Value Property in React Native for an onClick conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, properties, onclick

With React for the web if I had a button lay out and an onClick I would use a value property and then event.target.value to decide what to be done so that all my buttons had the same function passed in and what was done was based on the event. I would like the same functionality with react native. I'm using TouchableOpacity for my buttons but looking through the event that is given when pressed is huge with a lot of properties but it seems I can't use a value property, How is this done within React Native?

Answer (score 0):

The values are available on the `nativeEvent` object.

So your `onPress` method would be `onPress: (event) => doSomething(event.nativeEvent)`